# Change default "type" for problem detail API in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring Boot 3.x and I have a controller defined like this:

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = ["/my-controller"])
@Validated
class MyController {
    private val log = loggerFor<MyController>()

    @PutMapping("/{something}", consumes = [APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    fun test(
        @PathVariable("something") something: String,
        @Valid @RequestBody someDto: SomeDTO
    ) {
        log.info("Received $someDto")
    }
}

data class SomeDTO(val myBoolean: Boolean)
```

I've also enabled problem details ([RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807)) in my `application.yaml` file:

```
spring:
  mvc:
    problemdetails:
      enabled: true
```

When I make a request (in this example I'm using [rest assured](https://rest-assured.io/)) to `/my-controller/hello` with a json body that (intentionally) doesn't match the expected data (`myBoolean` is  *not* a valid boolean):

```kotlin
Given {
    port(<port>)
    contentType(JSON)
    body("""{ "myBoolean" : "not a boolean"}""")
    log().all()
} When {
    put("/my-controller/hello")
} Then {
    log().all().
    statusCode(400)
}
```

Then the response body looks like this:

```json
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Failed to read request",
    "instance": "/my-controller/hello"
}
```

My question is, how can I change the default `type` from `about:blank` to something else?

Comment: thank you, Did not realize I needed to enabled the problemdetails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `@ControllerAdvice` defined as follows:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    return ResponseEntity.of(
              Optional.of(
                Problem.builder()
                  .withType(URI.create("https://foobar.com/problem-definitions/blah"))
                  .withTitle("Bad Request")
                  .withDetail(ex.getMessage())
                  .withStatus(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                  .build()
              ));  
    }
```

}

It returns this for your example:

```
{
    "type": "https://foobar.com/problem-definitions/blah",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Type definition error: [simple type, class com.example.demo.web.LanguageController$SomeDTO]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.demo.web.LanguageController$SomeDTO`: non-static inner classes like this can only by instantiated using default, no-argument constructor\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 3]"
}
```

I used this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
    <artifactId>problem-spring-web-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.28.0-RC.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Note**

- The `ProblemDetail` class is available since `Spring Framework` **6**.

Therefore, the implementation in Spring 6 looks like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ProblemDetail> handleAllExceptions(
               Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ProblemDetail problemDetail = 
               ProblemDetail.forStatusAndDetail(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getMessage());
        problemDetail.setType(URI.create("https://foobar.com/problem-definitions/blah"));
        problemDetail.setInstance(URI.create("https://instance"));
        return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(problemDetail));
    }

}
```

Comment: I cannot seem to find the `Problem` class, in which package can I find it? Or are you referring to the `ProblemDetail` class in package `org.springframework.http`?

Comment: I used zalando Problem but Spring’s ProblemDetail is probably better.

Comment: ProblemDetail is new in Spring Framework 6 (Spring Boot 3) and requires Java17 so many classes have moved. I have added the zalando dependency (for before Spring 6) and an example of the Spring 6 implementation of ProblemDetail.

Comment: @JohnWilliams, `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` already provides an `@ExceptionHandler` for built-in exceptions and for any `ErrorResponseException` along with protected methods. I would work with that first, e.g. overriding `createResponseEntity` and checking if the body is an instance of `ProblemDetail` and editing its properties. Then if necessary, add additional `@ExceptionHandler` methods that also delegate to base class methods.

Comment: Note also that we [support customizations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-rest-exceptions-i18n) via ResourceBundle's for "detail" and "title", and could also add the same for "type".